# Why is this ArrayListStack throwing an EmptyStackException when it does contain elements?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, stack, throw

I am confused as to why I am getting an exception thrown when I am pushing elements into the `ArrayList`...It must be an issue with my `Push()` method, can anyone find the issue? I tried braces around the if statement and no luck, maybe even a problem with the `empty()` method?

Here is the exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at ArrayListStack.push(ArrayListStack.java:35)
    at StackMain.main(StackMain.java:7)
```

Code:

```
public class ArrayListStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
    // ArrayList to store items
    private ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    public ArrayListStack() {
    }

    /**
     * Checks if stack is empty.
     * @return true if stack is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean empty() {
        return this.size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Removes item at top of stack and returns it.
     * @return item at top of stack
     * @throws EmptyStackException
     *             if stack is empty.
     */
    public E push(E x) {
        if (empty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        list.add(x);
        return x;
    }

//MAIN METHOD
public class MainStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayListStack<Character> list = new ArrayListStack<>();
        list.push('A');
        list.push('B');
        list.push('C');
        System.out.print(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this` in `this.size() == 0;`?

Comment: There is a size() method that simply returns the size

Comment: Okay, I wasnt sure if the class was maybe extending Arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` shouldn't throw an exception when the stack is empty, since it will be empty before pushing the first element, which is fine.

Currently your first `push` (`list.push('A')`) is throwing an exception, since the stack is empty. Remove that condition from `push`. If your stack has a limit on the number of elements, you should have a condition in `push` that throws an exception if the stack is full.

Your

```
    if (empty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
```

check should be moved to the `pop()` method.

EDIT : The Javadoc of your `push()` method actually describes a `pop()` logic, which removes the element at the top of the stack and returns it. In `pop()` your empty check would be correct.

BTW, you also have an error in `empty()`. `this.size() == 0` should be `list.size() == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the moment you put your first element in the array using the code

```
list.push('A');
```

It will throw that exception because at that time the array will be empty.

Ideally you should throw this exception when you try to remove some element from the array, rather than while adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Removes item at top of stack and returns it.
 * @return item at top of stack
 * @throws EmptyStackException
 *             if stack is empty.
 */
public E pop() {
    if (empty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    E x = list.remove(0);
    return x;
}
/**
 * Add item at bottom of stack.
 */
 public void push(E x) {
    list.add(x);
 }
```

EmptyStackException should be thrown when we are trying to remove/get something from List. Note: Above code is not thread safe, if multiple thread try to push and pop in parallel. Then output is different as expected.